# how to calculate cumulative average of infected turtles in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

im trying to  calculate cumulative average of infected turtles in netlogo
i dont know what code exactly i should use and where to put it in the netlogo code
i did some tests and try to calculte the mean of the nodes but thats not correct.
i also tried to create a list but i didnt succed either.
where exactly in the code i should put the lines?

here some code:

```
observer> show mean [num-infected] of turtles
observer: 198
observer> show mean [num-infected] of turtles / length num-infected
observer> show mean [num-infected] of turtles / length [num-infected] of turtles
observer: 0.99
observer> show sum [num-infected] of turtles / length [num-infected] of turtles
observer: 197
observer> show count [num-infected] of turtles / length [num-infected] of turtles
observer> show mean [num-infected] of turtles / length [num-infected] of turtles
observer: 0.955
observer> show sum [num-infected] of turtles / length [num-infected] of turtles
observer: 191
observer> show sum [mean num-infected] of turtles
observer> show mean [ num-infected] of turtles
observer: 191
observer> show mean [ num-infected] of turtles
observer: 1
observer> show mean [ num-infected] of turtles
observer: 198
observer> show mean [ num-infected] of turtles
observer: 198
observer> show mean [ num-infected] of turtles
observer: 198
observer> show  [ num-infected] of turtles
observer> show count turtles with [infected? = true]
observer: 198
observer> show count turtles with [infected? = true] / length [num-infected] of turtles
observer: 0.99
observer> show count num-infected / count turtles with [infected? = true] 
ERROR: Expected an agentset here, rather than a list or block.
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the 'cumulative average of infected turtles'? Can you give an example?

Comment: hi
thanks for your answer,any way i'll give an example:
i have a model who shows for each tick how many nodes are been infected from amount of 200
what i want to calculate is the cumulative average of the nodes that been infected each time
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

See answer on the netlogo-users group at http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/netlogo-users/conversations/topics/16345

Travis Hinkelman writes:

> If I understand you correctly, then your reporter procedure should look like this:

```
to-report cumul-av-sum
;; drop the first member of the list, but not until there are at least 200 items in the list
if (length cumul-av-list > 200) [ set cumul-av-list but-first
cumul-av-list ]
;; add the number of raindrops created in last tick to the end of the list
set cumul-av-list lput num-infected cumul-av-list
report sum cumul-av-list
end
```

> This reporter procedure needs to be called every tick (presumably as part of a plot) to update the list correctly.